# Do I need to present a GDPR banner to IP addresses outside of GDPR regions?

Tags: united-states, internet, gdpr, international, european-union

The context of my question comes from [this comment](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/140499/what-region-codes-require-gdpr-compliance?noredirect=1#comment197570_140499):

> The problem with solving GDPR compliance with country codes is, it is not in general sufficient to determine if a user is covered by the GDPR. The GDPR requires you to comply with certain practices for data pertaining to people who are citizens or residents of EU countries. it doesn't specify that you only have to comply if their computer or IP address reports an EU country code. I as a European permanent resident could be using a US computer terminal at an internet cafe at the moment to log in to an account. That doesn't automatically mean my data aren't protected by the GDPR.

To give even more context, until I read this, I was under the impression that "GDPR banners" only need to be presented to users within the European Union/within regions with GDPR laws. Here is [my reply](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/140499/what-region-codes-require-gdpr-compliance?noredirect=1#comment197592_140499) to their comment:

> I'm really surprised to hear this. The [GDPR FAQ](https://gdpr.eu/faq/) (is this official?) says it applies to "anyone **in** EU territory." Their [What is GDPR](https://gdpr.eu/what-is-gdpr/) page says it applies to organizations that "target or collect data related to people **in** the EU." [Cookiebot](https://www.cookiebot.com/en/functions/) charges extra to conditionally show their banner based off of location (maybe that's only [useful] for CCPA). Do you have an official source for your statement?

Is their interpretation correct?

I want to know the technically correct answer *and* the "in practice" answer; bear with me on this example of the difference (if this is super confusing, please ignore it. My main question is the previous paragraph):

Let's *suppose* I'm technically correct and I only have to show banners to people in GDPR regions. VPNs could hypothetically make that irrelevant because VPNs can change your IP address, allowing someone *physically* in the EU to have an IP address of someone outside the EU. If I need to present these VPN users with a banner, I have no choice but to show the banner to everyone: I'll have no way of knowing what region their IP address comes from.

Let's suppose the company of the website is in California.

Comment: The first linked comment is incorrect.  The GDPR says absolutely nothing about citizenship.

Comment: The GDPR does not require a banner at all, that's just an admission by the website operator that they do not have a good reason to be collecting this data, and would like the user's permission to do it anyway. If you run an e-commerce site, you are allowed to process customer identity information such as name and address in the context of an order without ever displaying a banner, because it is widely understood that sending a parcel requires this information, creating legitimate interest until the order has been completed.

Comment: None of the existing answers are truly correct; the missing piece is whether the EU even has jurisdiction or not. An EU citizen connecting does not give the EU jurisdiction of itself any more than an Iranian citizen connecting to YouTube gives Iran jurisdiction over YouTube.

Comment: @Joshua - you leave one small tidbit unsaid: if the company (in your example, Google, Youtube, or Alphabet) has a presence in that country, they can be legally pressured into compliance. Even if they don't, they can lose revenue from ad announcers in those countries.

Comment: @Mindwin: Rather I focused my comment to companies that are likely to read law.stackexchange.com and believe the answers (that is, really small ones).

Comment: I came here to say what @SimonRichter said. The notion that GDPR requires banners is nonsense. What GDPR does require is that you obtain legitimate consent to collect and use data in sketchy ways, and this is irrelevant if you are not collecting and using data in sketchy ways.

Comment: `The GDPR does not require a banner at all ... If you run an e-commerce site, you are allowed to process customer identity information ... without ever displaying a banner` Is it that GDPR "does not require a banner" in this scenario, or that "GDPR does not apply"; in this scenario, are other aspects of GDPR that require webmaster action, even if a banner isn't one of them?

Comment: @DanielKaplan, the GDPR does not specify how consent is obtained. The banner is a common implementation as it insinuates that consent is required to proceed, but in fact the opposite is true: whenever there is a banner then consent is entirely optional. The main body of GDPR regulations concerns the backend: under which circumstances data may be shared with third parties (e.g. sending goods to a client means sharing the customer name and address with the postal service). The GDPR also has provisions for customers to request information about and deletion of data stored about them.

Comment: @DanielKaplan, the other important requirement in the GDPR is contact information for the compliance officer. The request for deletion is equivalent to revoking consent for processing beyond the minimum required, so ideally the backend keeps essential and nonessential information separate to facilitate this. For small to medium companies, information/deletion can be a manual process, but it may be a good idea to be able to automate this (e.g. like Facebook and Twitter allow you to download a large archive of all information they have about you).

Comment: @DanielKaplan, the GDPR specifies that for all data processing there needs to be a justification to keep the data. For a shopping site, the bare minimum is a shopping kart, a checkout process, order fulfillment and tax record retention -- these actions are permitted without extra consent. Creation of a customer account is optional, and requires the user to consent into having their data stored for longer than the duration of order processing; this consent can be collected at account creation time, and revoked by account deletion. GDPR disallows requiring customers to create an account.

Comment: @SimonRichter `The GDPR also has provisions for customers to request information about and deletion of data stored about them.` Hypothetical: what if the website only uses Google analytics and nothing else, it doesn't even have its own backend? If someone were to request deletion, I don't even know if it's *possible* to identify their data.

Comment: @SimonRichter - no, GDPR disalows requiring customers to create an account *with PII*. You absolutely can require them to create an anonymous account, and in some cases that could be necessary for a service to even function.

Comment: @DanielKaplan - if you can't identify PII because it's anonymised, then there is nothing to delete. But if it's not anonymized, it's your responsibility even if you pass it along to a 3rd party subprocessor.

Comment: Good grief. What wildly inaccurate ideas are going around here. To a first approximation, there is no such thing as a "GDPR banner". It would be rare for consent to be needed for e-commerce and where it is needed a "banner" is just not going to cut it. What you may be confused about is "cookie consent" banners, which are derived from a completely different piece of legislation, so asking about the GDPR will not help.

Comment: @FrancisDavey What I'm inferring is, "I'm asking the wrong questions," but I don't have enough information to know what the right questions are. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Davor `if you can't identify PII because it's anonymised...` As a layman, it's really hard for me to tell if stock Google Analytics—as in, what you get by default—is anonymized. This is for more than one reason: while *I* don't know how to identify an individual in Google Analytics, for all I know, there is a way to do it. In addition, I think I've read things like bits of anonymized data, when combined, can still count as PII. e.g., (making this up) an IP address and a time may narrow someone down to an individual, and Google Analytics does capture that much.

Comment: @Davor some services require PII to function.  Does the GDPR prohibit such services?

Comment: @phoog - no, that would fall under the "legitimate interest" and you don't even need consent for that.

Comment: @Davor how then does the GDPR "disallow requiring customers to create an account with PII?"

Comment: @phoog - it disallows requiring customers to give you unrelated data that you don't need (except to spy). For example, if you need to deliver a package, you can ask for address, and you don't even need to explicitly ask for consent, because you need an address to deliver a package. But you can't require them to make a full Facebook profile to create account. It's none of your business what their gender is, or religious preference etc. You can't make it a mandatory field if you don't have a legitimate interest.

Answer (score 27):

Your VPN scenario is the reason why you have to show the banner to everyone. If you somehow knew beyond any doubt that someone was not in the EU, then you would not have to show a banner, but because you can't verify that, you should always show the banner.

Doing so also protects against accidentally violating a similar law in another country; the GDPR is the best-known privacy law, but it is far from the only one.

Finally, there are non-legal reasons to show it for everyone. It's good practice to ask for people's permission before collecting their information even if it isn't mandatory. Many people in jurisdictions without strict privacy laws still appreciate having the choice to have sites collect less data, and once you've done the work to offer it where it's needed, you don't have to do anything more to show it for everyone; in fact, it's easier to give everyone the option since you don't have to worry about where users are.

Comment: I think this overstates the scope of the GDPR, and the other answers here are more nuanced – Art 3(2)(a) GDPR might not even trigger, since mere availability of a website to EU users doesn't imply GDPR applies. “Always show the banner” is of course safe and many sites do that, but the GDPR itself does not require it. GDPR only requires that you take *appropriate* measures to ensure compliance (see Art 24). Even though it will miss some cases, I think that IP-based geolocation is already a pretty good approach, in the sense that it can be reasonably defended in court if someone challenges it.

Comment: @amon meanwhile you're footing the bill for defense, which will most likely fall apart as soon as a counselor asks 'is there a guaranteed correlation between IP address and current physical location' and discovery finds that you are in fact holding identifying information of an EU located party without informed consent, or worse, that you aren't recording consent at all.

Comment: It is possible that a court would find the GDPR to not apply to those using non-EU VPNs, but until a court rules in that way, better safe than sorry. Once you've put in the effort to be compliant, you might as well give everyone the option; I'm not in a jurisdiction with strong online privacy laws, but I appreciate being able to opt out of tracking. It's good to give users the option even if you don't legally have to.

Comment: @Nohbdy is an "appropriate" measure defined as one that is correct 100% of the time?

Comment: @user253751, that would be up to the judge or jury after listening to counselors making their arguments, whose time you will pay for when opposing counsel clearly demonstrates that you engaged in willful ignorance to collect data without informed consent from regulated persons. The failure mode of your question depends on *somebody else's opinion*, and the whole situation is entirely avoidable. If you can clearly demonstrate that you *did* show the notification, you might even be able to get damages. If you're going to hedge bets, pick bets with better failure modes.

Comment: Hard to see legal action succeeding when someone in the EU utilised software to pretend they were outside .....

Comment: @deep64blue unless they're using a VPN for privacy and appearing to be outside the EU was not a goal. If an EU citizen has a non-EU IP, it's likely that they're *more* concerned about privacy than the average person.

Answer (score 14):

The [answer by user Someone](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/84824/17500) is correct, the GDPR applies to data associated with anyone physically in the EU, UK, or other places with a GDPR law.  The comment quoted in the question is incorrect on this point: citizenship is irrelevant to the GDPR. An EU citizen connecting while physically located in the US is not covered for that session.

But there are other conditions not mentioned in the answer by Someone. According to Article 3 of the GDPR, it applies only if the Data Controller (DC) "offers goods or services" with the EU (or UK or other relevant region) or "monitors the behavior" of natural persons in the EU or UK (or other relevant region, I will just write EU for the rest of this answer). That is interpreted to mean that the DC advertised in the EU, or presented pages in an EU language different from that in the DC's country, or otherwise showed intent to appeal to EU residents. Merely being accessible from the EU does not constitute "targeting". So a DC that makes no effort to appeal to EU residents is probably not covered by the GDPR.

But Someone was correct that it is good practice to ask all users for consent. In addition to the GDPR, there is the CCPA which applies to data collected from or about **any** resident of California, wherever that resident is currently located. There are somewhat similar laws in Colorado and several other US states, mostly newer and less publicized than the GDPR. One of these laws might well apply when the GDPR does not. Certainly one cannot reliably determine whether the GDPR applies to a particular site visitor based on the IP address used, and the GDPR cares only about the visitor's physical location, not the IP address.

Comment: `So a DC that makes no effort to appeal to EU residents is probably not covered by the GDPR.` What does "not covered" mean? Does that effectively mean, "GDPR can be ignored?" Let's say Bob's website uses Google analytics and no other third party service. The data is used for two purposes: as a form of feedback to improve the site, and to catch bugs that may not be noticed otherwise. The site is only in English. Does Bob require consent under GDPR?

Comment: Sorry if I come off like a jerk saying this, but I also wanted to add that there are a lot of typos in your response.

Comment: @Daniel Kaplan There is not enough info in your comment for a reasonable conclusion about Bob's site. First, does the GDPR apply at all. It is not clear if Bob is targeting any part of the EU. If not, GDPR will not apply. Second, the purposes you mention might fit under "legitimate interest". If so consent is not needed to be GDPR compliant. By "not covrtrf" I meant "GDPR does not apply at all, in acord with Art 3,

Comment: @Daniel Kaplan  I am well aware of my many typos. I make efforts to correct them. I have always been a poor typist, but in recent years vision issues have made this much worse. Feel free to notify me of remaining errors or edit to fix them, as you please.

Comment: I think you defined targeting as this (in code): `That is interpreted to mean that the DC advertised in the EU` Bob hasn't specifically advertised in the EU. They *self promote* their site on reddit/niche forums/chatrooms, but all are for global audiences. `presented pages in an EU language different from that in the DC's country` Nope. English only. `Otherwise showed intent to appeal to EU residents.` I'm not sure what else there could be beyond this. Bob's income is through Patreon, and that site accepts payment in many currencies, including EU currencies. Payment unlocks premium features.

Comment: Oh, and I don't know if this was implied/stated, but Bob lives in the US.

Comment: @DanielKaplan In an [unrelated answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/84757), I recently went through an analysis whether GDPR might apply to a website per Art 3(2). The answer summarizes relevant factors, and links to relevant EDPB guidelines on this matter. Patreon auto-converting currencies is tricky though, and there are [concerns](https://www.reddit.com/r/gdpr/comments/rvsr47/) this could cause GDPR to apply. (The link goes to a Reddit discussion providing important context, [original article here](https://www.theregister.com/2022/01/04/patreon_subs_sterling_mean_gdpr_sueballs/)).

Comment: I made the comment that likely inspired this question. Article 3 section 2a "the offering of goods or services, irrespective of whether a payment of the data subject is required, to such data subjects in the Union" Seems to imply however contrary to your answer that the determining factor is if the person was in the EU at the time the offer for goods or services was made, not at the the the data were collected. This is an important distinction.

Comment: For example: if I booked a tour with a US company that took place on US soil. The wording of that provision seems to imply that the GDPR also applies to data collected about me by the company while I am in the US as long as it is linked to the service that was offered to me while I was inside of the Union. As a more relevant example to the user's original question: If the website sold me a subscription service while I was in the Union, the GDPR protection still seems to apply to data collected when I use the subscription even outside of the EU.

Comment: @Tim Seguine The wording of the GDPR is not really clear on this point. There have not yet been many actual cases that dealt with situations when the DS was in the EU when goods were offered but not when data was collected, or vice versa. Interpretative statements from the various DPAs seem to suggest that it is the moment of data collection that counts most, but in the absence of court rulings one cannot be sure.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Okay, that's fair. I tried and failed to find case law on this point.

Comment: CCPA applies only to some for-profit businesses that do business in California. Essentially, you either need to be large enough to matter or to make most of your money selling user data. I'm not sure this is really comparable to the GDPR.

Comment: Apologies re: bring up the typos. Unfortunately, I don't have enough points on the site to fix them, because it doesn't change enough characters.

Comment: @Daniel Kaplan then postA COMMENT PINGING ME AND i WILL DO MY BESZT TO FIX THEM AS SOON AS i SEE IT. i WILL NOT BE OFFENDED.

Comment: @DavidSiegel will do in the future (or maybe a bunch of whitespace will allow me to go past the min limit). It looks like someone fixed them already though. Thanks again for everything

Comment: It would be terrible practice for an e-commerce site to seek GDPR consent for processing personal data as part of its usual business activities, because it would be very hard (1) to meaningfully inform the consent; (2) to avoid the appearance that if you say "no" you don't get to use the site (which means it probably isn't consent).

Comment: @Francis  If a business uses personal data (PD) and is subject to the GDPR, whether because of its locations or that of the Data Subjects, it **must** establish a lawful basis for such processing under GDPR Art 6. Depending on the nature of the data & purpose of processing, a basis other than consent may apply. But if no other basis applies, consent must be sought. There is no exception for "usual business activities" although "legitimate interest" might apply. If consent is refused a DS must still be able to use any aspect of the site that does not require processing of PD.

Answer (score 2):

You said, in a comment, that you may be asking the wrong question. I think a better way to put it would be that your question based on a confusion that is extremely common, so it deserves a clear answer.

From a European perspective, there are two different pieces of legislation at work.

- The [ePrivacy Directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_and_Electronic_Communications_Directive_2002)
- The [General Data Protection Regulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation)

(Rather than link directly to the legislation, I have linked to the Wikipedia pages from where you can find the legislation if you need it)

## ePrivacy

The popup banners you see are aimed at compliance with Article 5(3) of the ePrivacy directive.

### What the ePrivacy directive says

Article 5 begins:

> Member States shall ensure that the storing of information, or the gaining of access to information already stored, in the terminal equipment of a subscriber or user is only allowed on condition that the subscriber or user concerned has given his or her consent, having been provided with clear and comprehensive information, in accordance with Directive 95/46/EC, inter alia, about the purposes of the processing.

Cookies count as storing information on the equipment of a user, and requesting cookies counts as "gaining access". The default rule is that you may not do this without informed prior consent by the user.

There is an exception for essential cookies:

> This shall not prevent any technical storage or access for the sole purpose of carrying out the transmission of a communication over an electronic communications network, or as strictly necessary in order for the provider of an information society service explicitly requested by the subscriber or user to provide the service.

Here "essential" really means what it says. Google Analytics, while useful, really isn't essential and so any use of it had better obtain prior consent. The ePrivacy directive imports its definition of "consent" from the GDPR, so they mean the same thing (see recital 17).

By the way, for a long time you used to see "we care about your privacy" style popups that would allow you to say "yes" but if you wanted to say "no" you had to go through and select the cookies you did not want. This breaks a general rule of GDPR consent that consent should be as easy to refuse as to a give. "Yes" and "no" should be the same level of work.

### Where does this apply?

So, now to the question I think you are asking. Where does this apply? The directive itself does not give us much detail. It says (in article 3):

> This Directive shall apply to the processing of personal data in connection with the provision of **publicly available electronic communications services in public communications networks in the Community**, including public communications networks supporting data collection and identification devices.

I have emboldened the most crucial part.

Clearly, you have to at least have an electronic communications service and it must be available over a public communications network in the EU ("the Community"). But does that apply if my website just happens to be visible in the EU?

As far as I know, there's no direct authority on this point - in other words no case law. The European Data Protection Board ("EDPB") whose job it is to oversee the GDPR have given it some thought -see [Internal EDPB Document 04/2021 on criteria of territorial competence of supervisory authorities to enforce Article 5(3) of the ePrivacy Directive](https://edpb.europa.eu/our-work-tools/our-documents/internal-documents/internal-edpb-document-042021-criteria-territorial_nl). Their view is that it may depend on the law of the nation state in question (eg German law might come to a different decision than French law).

The proposed [ePrivacy Regulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPrivacy_Regulation) would clarify all this to some extent, though arguably in a more Draconian fashion. If this answer hangs around for a few years, that will become relevant.

In short: it is not particularly clear. If a service targets people in the EU as customers, I suspect that would fall within the directive. Otherwise I am not sure.

## GDPR

### Where does the GDPR apply?

The GDPR does have clear rules on jurisdiction. If you process personal data - where "process" includes storage etc - then there are four ways that you can come within the scope of the GDPR:

- That processing happens "within the context" of an establishment in the EU. For example, you have subsidiary with offices there which sells advertising that appears on your website (to pick an  example from Google Spain). This possibility does not depend on where the data subjects are or whether they are European or no.
- If a controller isn't established in the EU, but offers goods or services to data subjects in the EU.
- If a controller isn't established in the EU, but monitors the behaviour of data subjects in the EU
- If a controller, rather than being in the EU, is somewhere that the law of a member state applies as a matter of International Law (eg a ship or perhaps a spacecraft under the Outer Space Treaty).

### Do I need a consent banner under the GDPR?

Other than for ePrivacy compliance? No.

Well, to be pedantic, it might be possible to conceive of some such situation, but it would be very unlikely to happen in practice.

To amplify, the GDPR imposes a number of conditions on processing. One of these is that a controller must process "lawfully".

"Lawfully" obviously includes "not breaking the law", so if you breach the ePrivacy directive by not putting up a cookie banner and those cookies are also personal data, which would be common, then you also infringe the GDPR.

But the GDPR also says that "lawfully" includes a requirement to have what is known as a "lawful basis" for processing. Article 6 provides a short list of these.

One of these is "consent". The GDPR strongly discourages over-reliance on consent. For example, consent must be properly informed; it must be properly informed; and it must be freely given. This is very different from life under the data protection directive and I have spent a lot of time since 2018 (when the GDPR came into force) explaining to clients that they could nor, or should not, try to use consent as their lawful basis.

The two bases that usually apply are one that involves a contract between the data subject and the controller (if a controller contracts to supply a service to a data subject, that will involve processing personal data and will be lawful provided it is necessary) and a catch-all "legitimate interest". Google successfully relied on "legitimate interest" in the Google Spain case.

The thing is that a banner can just about allow someone to meaningfully decide whether they want non-essential cookies or not, though it can be tough to get that right, but not the complex processing that is typical in a more complicated relationship. Sure, you can point to a privacy notice or set of terms, but they are unlikely to be read or studied at the point when you need consent, even if data subjects can (and trust me they do) go back and read them later.

And "you may not use our service unless you consent..." does not sound like consent. Any "or else" works against the freedom of consent. This is why GDPR consent banners are (1) almost certainly useless and (2) almost never used. I have certainly never seen one.

Comment: Thanks for writing this thorough response! `The GDPR strongly discourages over-reliance on consent.` Maybe I missed it, but what's the alternative? Honestly, that's not my main question; my main question is, "If one uses Google analytics and stores no other data, what actions do they have to take to comply with all these laws?" "All these laws," is probably too vague a term for this site, but a webmaster isn't too concerned if they broke  law or another, they just want to know how to not break the law. Is there a way for a webmaster to cover all their bases at once?

Comment: I think I did mention that for most purposes you would use either legitimate interest or necessary for performance etc of a contract, depending on the data. Google analytics would be legitimate interest. You'd have to show that it passed the legitimate interest test; declare it in your privacy notice; and worry about whether Google analytics is specifically problematic (and it may be) but maybe a question focussed on analytics is a better place for that, since it covers many services.

Comment: Thanks for the help, once again. I'll try to write that as a question soon.

Answer (score 0):

### Depends on your own location

The first question is about your own location. If you (as a data controller or processor) are located within EU, then GDPR applies for any and all processing of personal data you do, no matter who is the data subject.

If you are located outside of EU then the relevant part of GDPR is Article 3.2 about territorial scope:

> This Regulation applies to the processing of personal data of data subjects who are in the Union by a controller or processor not established in the Union, where the processing activities are related to:
>
> (a) the offering of goods or services, irrespective of whether a payment of the data subject is required, to such data subjects in the Union; or
>
> (b) the monitoring of their behaviour as far as their behaviour takes place within the Union.

So if the section applies (i.e. you're offering goods or services or monitoring behavior of these people) then the key criterion is whether these people are "in the Union". IP address might be a way to establish that, however, you may have more relevant information (e.g. address of the user or self-indicated location) in which case you should respect that even if the IP address is located outside of EU.

Comment: The IP address is never a good way to **establish** if a person is "in the union. At best it gives a fair first estimate. There will be both false positives and false negatives using geolocation from  IP addresses.

Comment: IP addresses are not a valid way to determine location. They can be changed with VPNs. A German user could easily visit a site with a California IP, for example, by using a VPN provider located in California. (Edit: I began typing before @DavidSiegel posted his comment.)

Comment: @Someone: It's correct that VPN's make it hard to determine the actual location of the user. But there's no jurisprudence yet whether this matters. There is a counter-argument that VPN users can be considered to be outside the EU, like tourists. This is especially the case since VPN's these days offer a choice of originating IP. That German VPN user voluntarily chose to appear American.

Comment: @Someone Non-VPN IP addresses are fairly reliable for country-level attribution, which is probably enough for compliance purposes. The CJEU was asked about IP geolocation for compliance in C-131/12 but declined to rule on that aspect due to procedural reasons, though its comments suggest that they might be good enough. A data controller can address VPN concerns by treating all known VPN IP addresses as EU-located. These aspects of GDPR are not black and white, a reasonable effort already goes a long way. GDPR does not intend to force its rules upon purely foreign matters.

Comment: @Someone Is the site responsible for knowing the user's actual location if the user takes active steps to lie about their location? Common sense would suggest no, probably not

Comment: @amon `A data controller can address VPN concerns by treating all known VPN IP addresses as EU-located.` Wouldn't that only address VPN concerns for *known* VPN IP addresses? I'm assuming that list is incomplete and constantly changing.

Comment: @user253751 Using IP addresses to infer a (rough) location is a heuristic, not an intended use case of the protocol. Connecting from a "remote" network is no more a lie than, say, changing the preferred language in your browser.

Comment: @RutherRendommeleigh Each IP address is registered to a company which is registered in a country.  Inferring a street address is heuristic-based. Inferring a service provider is not heuristic-based.

Comment: @user253751: You have defeated your own argument: if the country is tied to the IP address, then it follows that you cannot deduce the user's location from the IP address, since the IP address of a device has nothing to do with the physical location of the user. Just three examples: my work computer always has an IP address registered to my employer's headquarters, regardless of which country I happen to be in. My desktop always has an IP address registered to my ISP, regardless of which country I am in. My jumphost always has the same IP, which I bought from a reseller which resides in a …

Comment: … country (I assume for tax reasons) I've never been to, probably never will go to, and cannot even pronounce.

Comment: @JörgWMittag And common sense says that if you're in France but access the Internet through remote access to your work computer in the USA, that's your own damn fault that websites don't think you're in the EU. However, I don't know whether the law obeys common sense. It often doesn't.

Comment: @user253751: By the same argument, you could say that if you use the IP address (which has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with geographical location) of a device (whose physical location is only weakly correlated with the physical location of the user of said device) to determine the geographical location of the user, that's your own damn fault, and I *hope* that it would be common sense that using something that has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with physical location to determine a physical location is not a good idea.